# Validation of cronjob and crontab - lynx -dump URL

Tags: linux, cron

I have SSH and 2 cronjobs to add:

1. Every Friday, every 15 minutes and start on 01:00AM (end can be at 23:00AM - hour before midnight)

   ```
   * /15 1-23 * * 5 lynx -dump http://www.mysite.com/dir_name/nl.php?show=send
   ```
2. Every day at 02:00AM

   ```
   * 2 * * * lynx -dump http://www.mysite.com/dir_name/nl.php?show=get_rss
   ```

When I am trying to save, it says an error "bad hour".  Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Syntax errors:

```
* /15 1-23 * * 5 lynx -dump http://www.mysite.com/dir_name/nl.php?show=send
^^^^^
```

should be

```
*/15 1-23 * * 5 lynx -dump http://www.mysite.com/dir_name/nl.php?show=send
^^^^
```

note the space.

#### Frequency errors:

> Every Friday, every 15 minutes and start on 01:00AM (end can be at 23:00AM - hour before midnight)

Yours will execute from 1.00 to 23.45 every 15 min:

```
*/15 1-23 * * 5 lynx -dump http://www.mysite.com/dir_name/nl.php?show=send
```

It should be like this:

```
*/15 1/22 * * 5 lynx -dump http://www.mysite.com/dir_name/nl.php?show=send
0 23 * * 5 lynx -dump http://www.mysite.com/dir_name/nl.php?show=send
```

> Every day at 02:00AM

Yours will execute every minute at hour 2, meaning at 2.00, 2.01, ..., 2.59:

```
* 2 * * * lynx -dump http://www.mysite.com/dir_name/nl.php?show=get_rss
```

It should be like this:

```
0 2 * * * lynx -dump http://www.mysite.com/dir_name/nl.php?show=get_rss
```

Comment: I think the 2nd line is fine, @TimCooper.

Comment: Not quite.  The command will execute for ever minute of 2am, not just once.

Comment: Sure, I was looking for "syntax" errors. Updated accordingly, thanks @TimCooper